# How to display the maxlength countdown remaining characters for custom form fields

Tags: drupal-6, maxlength

I have installed the maxlength module. It show the countdown of the remaining characters under the body field.
And now I want to display the count down for the custom form fields.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they've added this feature. See this thread: http://drupal.org/node/1175172